# Duplicate rows instead of overwriting rows data using COPY command to load data from Amazon S3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-s3

```
copy Agent1
from 's3://my-bucket/Reports/Historical Metrics Report (1).csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::my-role:role/RedshiftRoleForS3'
csv
null as '\000'
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

I am using this (above) to pull the data from s3 to redshift table. its working fine but there is one problem as when data is pulled/copied very first time it inserted into table but when the data get updated in s3 bucket file and we run the same query what it does is add the whole new rows of data instead of overwriting the already created rows.

How to stop duplication? i just want that when the data get updated on s3 file, after running Copy Command my data (rows) get overwritten and replaced the rows data with new data.

[Here is the screenshot - rows are being added with updated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xna4E.jpg)

Comment: If you want to totally replace the existing data, you can `TRUNCATE` the table before performing `COPY`. That will erase the contents.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. `TRUNCATE` seems the best solution to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift doesn't enforce uniqueness.  See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

To update a table you will need to COPY the data to a "staging" table and perform an UPSERT process. See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to **empty the table** prior to loading data via `COPY`, then you can use the `TRUNCATE` command to empty the table:

```
TRUNCATE tablename;
```

Note that this cannot be rolled-back within a commit.

Using `TRUNCATE` is much more efficient than `DELETE FROM tablename` because it immediately removes all storage associated with the table.

Comment: Can we use ALTER `TABLE target_table_name APPEND FROM source_table_name`  instead of truncate the table in our Copy Command. The requirement is to append/update the table instead of truncating it.

Comment: i just want to load/copy the data from s3 using Copy command and append/insert it into my redshift table, only the updated data should be inserted/appended in rows instead of adding new rows to be added.

Comment: No. Amazon Redshift does not have an `Upsert` command. When using the `COPY` command, all rows will be loaded into the table. If you want to insert/append, see: [Use a staging table to perform a merge (upsert) - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html)